# Rails 3.2 M-N association search geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, controller

I have following 2 models

```
class Watersporttyp < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :activities
  has_many :watersportspots, through: :activities          
 end

class Watersportspot < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :watersporttyp_ids, :latitude, :longitude, address
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :activities
  has_many :watersporttyps, through: :activities
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude      
end
```

In my View I have this search form

```
 <%= form_tag watersportspots_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <div class="row collapse">

    <div class="small-10 columns">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "button prefix" %>
    </div>

  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
    <% Watersporttyp.all.each do |watersporttyp| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "typs[]", watersporttyp.id %>
      <%= watersporttyp.name %><br>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

My question is how do I set up my controller to perform search by filtering nearby location with the attributes from the checkboxes "types[]"

I tried this in my controller, but it doesn't work

```
@watersportspots = Watersportspot.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance, :units => :km).join(:watersporttyp).where(:watersporttyp => params[:typs])
```

I'm using the geocoder gem for geocoding and my system is using ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2